# How to stop Qweb calling Computing method of computed field to generate results in odoo9?

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

I'm using odoo9, I've a model which has computed fields,and these fields are editable also,so user can change the values. But when generating PDF of this model, Qweb calling computing method and recalculating fields, hence it is not showing modified values. I dont want such behaviour

Comment: share the code - I am working now on reports for accounting in Odoo 9 so might have something.

Comment: What about storing the field? So it only recomputes the values if asked, too (changing dependent fields). As for the manipulation: please add your code, because that's sounding like a mistake to me.

Comment: Computed fields are (usually) not editable, only the fields that they depend on. So, your question is not clear what you are trying to do and what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @miw , I mean Stored Computed fields. Qweb is calling computing method for each computed field and hence not showing correct values since user might have modified values. But any way, to get out of it, I called a method and fetched the exact values from db and then showed them in report. :)

Comment: @CZoellner, Thanks for your response :) , but I achieved what I wanted by calling a class method from Qweb to fetch exact values from db .

Comment: You should share it as answer to your question ;-)

Comment: @CZoellner, Yes for sure

Answer (score 0):

To stop Qweb Calling Compute method for computed fields, fetch stored values from db like that :

```
<openerp>
<data>
    <template id="payslip">
        <t t-call="report.html_container">
            <t t-foreach="docs" t-as="doc">
                <t t-foreach="doc.get_info(doc.id)" t-as="res">
                  <t t-set="name" t-value="res['name']"/>
                  <t t-set="designation" t-value="res['designation']"/>
                  <t t-set="required_hours" t-value="res['required_hours']"/>
                  <t t-set="regular_worked_hour" t-value="res['regular_worked_hour']"/>
                  <t t-set="vacation_credited" t-value="res['vacation_credited']"/>
                  <t t-set="vacation_encash" t-value="res['vacation_encash']"/>
                  <t t-set="overtime_hours" t-value="res['overtime_hours']"/>
                  <t t-set="work_from_home_hrs" t-value="res['work_from_home_hrs']"/>
                  <t t-set="total_plus_manual" t-value="res['total_plus_manual']"/>
                  <t t-set="total_this_period" t-value="res['total_this_period']"/>
                  <t t-set="mobile_allowance" t-value="res['mobile_allowance']"/>
                  <t t-set="internet_allowance" t-value="res['internet_allowance']"/>
                  <t t-set="bonus_amount" t-value="res['bonus_amount']"/>
                  <t t-set="net_salary" t-value="res['net_salary']"/>
                  <t t-set="salary_tax" t-value="res['salary_tax']"/>
                  <t t-set="vacation_opening_bal" t-value="res['vacation_opening_bal']"/>
                  <t t-set="advance_salary" t-value="res['advance_salary']"/>
                  <t t-set="vacation_earned" t-value="res['vacation_earned']"/>
                  <t t-set="loan_amount" t-value="res['loan_amount']"/>
                  <t t-set="vacation_taken" t-value="res['vacation_taken']"/>
                  <t t-set="salary_brought_forward" t-value="res['salary_brought_forward']"/>
                  <t t-set="vacation_encash" t-value="res['vacation_encash']"/>
                  <t t-set="salary_payable" t-value="res['salary_payable']"/>
                  <t t-set="vacation_closing_bal" t-value="res['vacation_closing_bal']"/>
                  <t t-set="join_date" t-value="res['join_date']"/>
                  <t t-set="month_name" t-value="res['month_name']"/>
                  <t t-set="pay_period" t-value="res['pay_period']"/>
                  <t t-set="stand_salary" t-value="res['stand_salary']"/>
                  <t t-set="monthly_rate" t-value="res['monthly_rate']"/>
                  <t t-set="hourly_rate" t-value="res['hourly_rate']"/>
                  <t t-set="stand_salary" t-value="res['stand_salary']"/>


                <div class="header">
                        <span>
                            <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-3">
                                <strong>Name:</strong>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-xs-3">
                                <span t-esc="name"/>
                            </div>
                            </div>

                        </span>


                        <span style="margin-top:-2px !important;">
                            <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-3">
                                <strong>Designation:</strong>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-xs-5">
                                <span t-esc="designation"/>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                        </span>


                        <span style="margin-top:0px;">
                            <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-3">
                                <strong>Appointment Date:</strong>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-xs-3">
                                <span t-esc="join_date"/>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                        </span>

                        <span style="margin-top:0px;">
                            <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-3">
                                <strong>Salary Type:</strong>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-xs-5">
                                <span>Monthly/
                                    <span t-esc="month_name"/>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                        </span>


                        <span style="margin-top:0px;">
                            <div class="row">

                            <div class="col-xs-3">
                                <strong>Pay Date:</strong>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-xs-5">

                                <span t-esc="time.strftime('%B %d %Y')"/>
                            </div>

                            </div>
                        </span>

                        <span style="margin-top:0px;">
                            <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-3">
                                <strong>Pay Period:</strong>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-xs-5">
                                <span t-esc="pay_period"/>
                            </div>
                            </div>
                        </span>
                </div>

                    <div class="page" >

                        <span style="margin-top:0px;">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-6">
                                    <strong>Standard Salary:</strong>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-xs-5">
                                    <span t-esc="stand_salary"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </span>


                        <span style="margin-top:0px;">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-6">
                                    <span>Current Monthly Basic Rate:</span>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-xs-5">
                                    <span t-esc="monthly_rate"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </span>


                        <span style="margin-top:0px;">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-6">
                                    <span>Current Hourly Rate:</span>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-xs-5">
                                    <span t-esc="hourly_rate"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </span>


                        <span style="margin-top:0px;">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-6">
                                    <span>Total Hours This Period:</span>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-xs-5">
                                    <span t-esc="required_hours"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </span>


                        <span style="margin-top:0px;">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-6">
                                    <span>Regular Hours Worked This Period:</span>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-xs-5">
                                    <span t-esc="regular_worked_hour"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </span>


                        <span style="margin-top:0px;">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-6">
                                    <span>Vacations Credited:</span>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-xs-5">
                                    <span t-esc="vacation_credited"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </span>





                        <span style="margin-top:0px;">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-6">
                                    <span>Vacations Encash:</span>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-xs-5">
                                    <span t-esc="vacation_encash"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </span>


                        <span style="margin-top:0px;">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-6">
                                    <span>Over Time Hours:</span>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-xs-5">
                                    <span t-esc="overtime_hours"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </span>


                         <span style="margin-top:0px;">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-6">
                                    <span>Work from Home Hours:</span>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-xs-5">
                                    <span t-esc="work_from_home_hrs"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </span>




                        <span style="margin-top:0px;">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-6">
                                    <span>Total Hours Payable:</span>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-xs-5">
                                    <span t-esc="total_plus_manual"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </span>


                        <span style="margin-top:0px;">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-6">
                                    <span>Total For This Period:</span>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-xs-5">
                                    <span t-esc="total_this_period"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </span>


                        <span style="margin-top:0px;">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-6">
                                    <span>Add: Mobile Allowance:</span>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-xs-5">
                                    <span t-esc="mobile_allowance"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </span>


                        <span style="margin-top:0px;">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-6">
                                    <span>Add: Internet Allowance:</span>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-xs-5">
                                    <span t-esc="internet_allowance"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </span>


                        <span style="margin-top:0px;">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-6">
                                    <span>Bonus:</span>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-xs-5">
                                    <span t-esc="bonus_amount"/>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </span>


                        <span style="margin-top:0px;">
                            <div class="row">

                                <div class="col-xs-6">
                                    <strong>Net Salary (Round to Next 100):</strong>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-xs-5">
                                    <span t-esc="net_salary"></span>
                                </div>


                            </div>


                        </span>


                        <span style="margin-top:0px;">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-6">
                                    <span>Less: Withholding Tax On Salary:</span>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-xs-2">
                                    <span t-esc="salary_tax"></span>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-xs-3">
                                    <span>Vacation Opening Bal</span>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-xs-1">
                                    <span t-esc="vacation_opening_bal"></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </span>


                        <span style="margin-top:0px;">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-6">
                                    <span>Less: Advance Salary:</span>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-xs-2">
                                    <span t-esc="advance_salary"></span>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-xs-3">
                                    <span>Vacation Earned (+)</span>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-xs-1">
                                    <span t-esc="vacation_earned"></span>
                                </div>


                            </div>
                        </span>


                        <span style="margin-top:0px;">
                            <div class="row">

                                <div class="col-xs-6">
                                    <span>Less Loan:</span>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-xs-2">
                                    <span t-esc="loan_amount"></span>
                                </div>


                                <div class="col-xs-3">
                                    <span>Vacation Taken (-)</span>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-xs-1">
                                    <span t-esc="vacation_taken"></span>
                                </div>

                            </div>


                        </span>


                        <span style="margin-top:0px;">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-6">
                                    <span>Carried Over to Next Month [Short (+) Excessive (-)]:</span>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-xs-2">
                                    <span t-esc="salary_brought_forward"></span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-3">
                                    <span>Vacation Encash (-)</span>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-xs-1">
                                    <span t-esc="vacation_encash"></span>
                                </div>


                            </div>
                        </span>

                        <span style="margin-top:0px;">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-6">
                                    <Strong>Salary Amount Payable:</Strong>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-xs-2">
                                    <span t-esc="salary_payable"></span>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-xs-3">
                                    <strong>Vacation Closing Bal</strong>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-xs-1">

                                    <strong t-esc="vacation_closing_bal"></strong>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </span>


                    </div>


                </t>
            </t>
        </t>
    </template>

</data>
```

And this python code:

```
    def get_info(self, id):

    data = self.env['payslip.deta'].search([("id", "=", id)])
    dict =  {'name': data.employee_id.name_related, 'designation':data.employee_id.job_id.name,\
             'required_hours': data.required_hours ,'regular_worked_hour':data.regular_worked_hour, \
             'vacation_credited':data.vacation_credited, 'vacation_encash':data.vacation_encash,\
             'overtime_hours':data.overtime_hours, 'work_from_home_hrs':data.work_from_home_hrs,\
             'total_plus_manual':data.total_plus_manual, 'total_this_period': data.total_this_period,\
             'mobile_allowance':data.mobile_allowance,'internet_allowance':data.internet_allowance,\
             'bonus_amount': data.bonus_amount, 'net_salary': data.net_salary, 'salary_tax':data.salary_tax,\
             'vacation_opening_bal':data.vacation_opening_bal, 'advance_salary':data.advance_salary,\
             'vacation_earned':data.vacation_earned, 'loan_amount': data.loan_amount,\
             'vacation_taken':data.vacation_credited,'salary_brought_forward':data.salary_brought_forward,\
             'vacation_encash':data.vacation_encash, 'vacation_closing_bal': data.vacation_closing_bal,\
             'salary_payable':data.get_net_salary_in_slip(),'join_date':data.get_emp_join_date(data.employee_id.join_date),\
             'month_name':data.get_month_name(data.month),'pay_period':data.get_pay_period_in_slip(data.year,data.month),
             'stand_salary':data.get_emp_stand_salary_in_slip(data.employee_id), 'monthly_rate':data.get_monthly_basic_rate_in_slip(),\
             'hourly_rate':data.get_hourly_rate_in_slip()

            }
    return [dict]
```